# Creating variable numbers of text boxes using Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

My website has a search bar, and it takes in a search query. Depending on the length of the query (number of characters, for example), I want to create more or less text boxes, for a maximum of 10. (The total number doesn't really matter -- I just don't know how to make a variable number of text boxes in general.) Thus, what would be the best way to do this?

```
@app.route('/searchQuery', methods=['POST'])
def searchQuery():
     searchquery = request.form['searchQuery']
     print searchquery
    searchquery += " || python added this line!"
    return render_template('simplesearch.html', content=searchquery)
```

```html
<div><center>{{content}}</center></div>
```

However, if I want to create new divs for up to 10 unique items, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide a bit more than what you have in order to get an appropriate response. What do you mean you want to create text boxes based on the length of the query? So are you saying if your query is 100 characters long, create 100 text boxes?

Comment: @JasonHeine I updated the description. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

So a **basic** example of what you are trying to do. Note: this is quick code but should lead you in the right direction:

**your_file.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/searchQuery', methods=['POST'])
def search_query():
    sq_ = request.form.get('searchQuery')
    print(sq_)

    return render_template('simplesearch.html', search_query=sq_)
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search_query') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**simplesearch.html**

```
<table>
    {% for x in range(search_query | int) %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="{{ x }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Basically you are going to capture the "number" that you pass in. I would suggest putting in some checks. Then use Jinja to render the text boxes. Which you can then post to a new page or do whatever with it.

Comment: thanks for the response - I'll try it out and see how it goes!!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Comment: how would I check if search_query is null? Is this javascript within the % signs?

Comment: It is Jinja templating. I would suggest reading up on the flask request documentation. You can check via JavaScript, or in Python. Python would be if sq_ is not None. I would suggest going through the flask documentation, their site is how I learned most of the stuff http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/